# Change value of tensor by multi condition

Tags: python, tensor

Let preds be a tensor with shape (32,256,192)

```
#preds[preds<0.15] = 0.0
#preds[preds<0.45 and preds>0.15] = 0.33
```

when running the first line of code it works but when running the second line of code it gives this error

```
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
preds[preds < 0.15] = 4
preds[preds < 0.45] = 3
preds[preds < 0.75] = 2
preds[preds < 1] = 1
preds[preds == 4] = 0
preds[preds == 3] = 0.33
preds[preds == 2] = 0.66
```